# R: Where to insert personality quiz function for a simple Shiny web app

Tags: r, shiny

My task is to create a simple Shiny web app based upon a simple sorting hat quiz program. I'm pretty confused on how to integrate the program below into the skeletal ui.R and server.R.

HogwartsQuiz = function(){

```
q.c = readline(prompt = "How do you describe yourself? (brave; ambitious; loyal; intelligent): ")
if (q.c == "brave"){
    paste("You belong in Gryffindor!")
} else if (q.c == "ambitious") {
    paste("You belong in Slytherin!")
} else if (q.c == "loyal"){
    paste("You belong in Hufflepuff!")
} else{
    paste ("You belong in Ravenclaw!")
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you are a beginner in terms of Shiny. There are great resources out there, personally I would recommend [this Gallery](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) as a start and then searching for any building blocks/ widgets I need. Also, [this Cheat Sheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/shiny.pdf) served me well at the beginning!  I have put in the effort to help you to get your Shiny Experience started (see below).
Best Lea

```
library(shiny)

#Setting Up the User Interface
ui <- fluidPage( 
  h2("Hogwarts Quiz"), #h2 comes form html style and simply is determining basically the text size
  selectInput("UserInput",  # This is the name of the variable the User Input will be saved to
              "How do you describe yourself?", #This is what will be displayed for the user
              choices = c("","brave", "ambitious", "loyal","intelligent")), # the preset choices
  h4(textOutput("Result")) # h4 is text size again; here will be the Output send to 
) 
server <- function(input, output){  # this is the function body for the App evaluating Input
  HogwartsQuiz =function(q.c){  # Your function (could be also set outside of shiny body)
    if (q.c == "brave"){
      QuizResult="You belong in Gryffindor!"
    } else if (q.c == "ambitious") {
      QuizResult="You belong in Slytherin!"
    } else if (q.c == "loyal"){
      QuizResult="You belong in Hufflepuff!"
    } else if(q.c == "intelligent"){
      QuizResult="You belong in Ravenclaw!"
    }else{
      QuizResult=""
    }
    return(QuizResult)
  }
  output$Result <- renderText({  #render is observing any change of the input
    HogwartsQuiz(input$UserInput) # is taken users, handing over to the function
                                  # the function's result will be finally send to the Output
  })
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```